# 16-bit to 8-bit conversion of volumetric data (iOS + OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am loading volumetric data as 8 bit GL_LUMINANCE textures.

I had posted a question on [how to directly load a 16-bit luminance texture in OpenGL ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072990/creating-a-16-bit-luminance-texture-in-opengl-es-2-0-on-ios), but I didn't get a solution. So to load 16-bit data, I am trying to rescale the 16-bit values to 8-bit as follows:

```
newvol[i] = 255 * (oldVol[i] + 32768)/66536;
```

I confirmed that the 16-bit data is signed short. For the data set shown below, I found the min/max values to be (-32768, 32516)

But the above conversion produces artifacts (clipping?) as shown in a cross section below:

[image]

Is the conversion wrong? Is there a better way to convert to 8-bit?

Comment: You should divide by 65535 not 65536 (if you have max (65535) it should be normalized to 1.0 so 65535 / 65535). You can simplify the formula to : newvol[i] = (oldVol[i] + 32768) / 257;

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that still produces the clipping artifacts...